# Having Emacs "always on top"

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I was wondering if there was a way (at least on Ubuntu, which I am using) to have Emacs "always on top" i.e it can be seen even when some other window is put forward.
I don't know if it can be done inside emacs or requires some system configuration.
Thank you!

EDIT: I just realized I could right-click on the emacs window and check "Always on top", which is what I wanted to have...

Comment: Ah! I assumed you meant to 'always' have it always on top. i.e. configure every Emacs window you open, to show up on top.

Comment: @submachine: Actually I am having a look at your DevilsPie, it seems to be very convenient to be able to script how you want your different windows to be displayed, thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu is not important here. The window manager is what matters (KDE/GNOME/fvwm...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall this program:
http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie

The introduction says, and I quote:
"A totally crack-ridden program for freaks and weirdos who want precise control over what windows do when they appear. If you want all XChat windows to be on desktop 3, in the lower-left, at 40% transparency, you can do it."

You'll have to write a '.ds' script in ~/.devilspie to get what you want though.

Something like:

```
(if
  (matches (application_name) "^Emacs")
  (begin
    (above)
  )
)
```

AFAIK, it works with GNOME/Metacity.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a ubuntu question but this is one **WINDOWS** implementation. Though I have not personally tested it http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-pin-any-application-window-to-the-top/

Comment: @submachine: yes i explicitly stated that in the answer too

Comment: @mangubug, true. Maybe we can modify the question slightly and have a program listed for each OS/WM :)